# How to Remove an untitled column without header in DataGridView in c# window form

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net, window

**I am importing excel data into datagridview and I have to use this data into my word documents using parameters. But unfortunately, the excel numbering also comes inside gridview. It is without header whom I unable to remove either use using index either anything. nore can hide because it doesn't have a header. so because of this, I am unable to select any row because to this first untitled header. Please help me I really need help. either tell me any code by using that code if i can import data from excel without row numbering of excel (Mean red circle column of pic). Either any way to destroy the first column that doesn't have header **

[image]

```
OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openfile.Filter = "XLS files (*.xls, *.xlt)|*.xls;*.xlt|XLSX files (*.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xltx, *.xltm)|*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xltx;*.xltm|ODS files (*.ods, *.ots)|*.ods;*.ots|CSV files (*.csv, *.tsv)|*.csv;*.tsv|HTML files (*.html, *.htm)|*.html;*.htm";
        openfile.FilterIndex = 2;
        if (openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ExcelFile ef = ExcelFile.Load(openfile.FileName);




            DataGridViewConverter.ExportToDataGridView(ef.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet, this.dataGridView1, new ExportToDataGridViewOptions() { ColumnHeaders = true  });
            this.dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to tell for every column what exactly computer want
20

The error says "The index is out of range". That means you were trying to index an object with a value that was not valid. If you have two books, and I ask you to give me your third book, you will look at me funny. This is the computer looking at you funny. You said - "create a collection". So it did. But initially the collection is empty: not only is there nothing in it - it has no space to hold anything. "It has no hands".

Then you said "the first element of the collection is now 'ItemID'". And the computer says "I never was asked to create space for a 'first item'." I have no hands to hold this item you are giving me.

In terms of your code, you created a view, but never specified the size. You need a
**

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "FileRow";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "FIRSTNAME1";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "LASTNAME1";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "ADDRESS1";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "CITY1";
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "STATE1";
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = "ZIP1";
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].Name = "FIRSTNAME2";
            dataGridView1.Columns[8].Name = "LASTNAME2";
            dataGridView1.Columns[9].Name = "ADDRESS2";
            dataGridView1.Columns[10].Name = "CITY2";

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvCount.Rows)
    {
        row.HeaderCell.Value = "";     // Use :: null  OR "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't making the column visibility to `false` like the following solve your problem:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Comment: sir i already used this this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false; and  this.dataGridView1.Columns.Remove(""); . but problem is this is not working on untilled column

Comment: sir . We have two ways to remove a column 1) is header name 2) is index number . i am agree with it but problem is this red circle is not in index as well , when i do index 0 or 1 it start from header ones not from the untitled one

Comment: sir can i connect with you on skype pls ? for this problem's solution

Answer (score 1):

Just remove column from DataGridViewColumnCollection as:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Remove("");
```

This must work, my code sample

```
private void AddRow()
    {
        this.dgvCount.Columns.Add("", "");
        this.dgvCount.Columns.Add("Stat", "Stat");
        this.dgvCount.Columns[""].Width = 100;
        this.dgvCount.Columns["Stat"].Width = 100;


        this.dgvCount.Rows.Add("1", "100");
        this.dgvCount.Rows.Add("2","200");
        this.dgvCount.Rows.Add("3","300");
        this.dgvCount.Rows.Add("4", "400");

        this.dgvCount.Columns.Remove("");
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I zoomed pic & noticed that this is **not DataGridViewColumn** rather than **these are Row Headers** which were text when you import data from excel, i don't know why, Now just use following code to clear text of rows header ::

```
//Remove text from Row Header Cell
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dgvCount.Rows)
        {
            row.HeaderCell.Value = "";     // Use :: null  OR "";
        }
```

This should work !!

Comment: sir i already used this this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false; and  this.dataGridView1.Columns.Remove(""); . but problem is this is not working on untilled column

Comment: sir . We have two ways to remove a column 1) is header name 2) is index number . i am agree with it but problem is this red circle is not in index as well , when i do index 0 or 1 it start from header ones not from the untitled one

Comment: sir can i connect with you on skype pls ? for this problem's solution